# How to resolve this issue Error while executing c:\Users\user\...\cmake.exe with arguments {-HF:\My Project\app\sr.......-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang}

Tags: android, cmake

I am not so much familiar with Cmake of the android studio. Recently I decided to use it for the native interface. Every time I build the project from build tool, I am getting the aforesaid error in gradle sync message.
My CMakeLists.txt file

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library(native-lib
            SHARED
            src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)`

My build.gradle (app level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId="com.example.user.MyProject"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags '-frtti'
                arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang'
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
            }

        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           // proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

dependencies {

What am I doing wrong here?? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post entire content of gradle file.

Comment: Thanks Parth Patel for response, but which one?? I've post entire app level gradle except some dependencies.

Comment: above code cannot showing dependcies. So, you have to repost entire code. then we can explore about actual problem.

Comment: Parth Patel, I think this error has no connection with all these dependencies. I think i am doing some wrong in both level of gradle or cmakelists.txt but i could not find out this.

Comment: what is the  > I am getting the aforesaid error in gradle sync message.  ?

Comment: shizhen, actually i am getting error 'External native build issues. Build command failed. Error while executing c:\Users\user\…\cmake.exe with arguments {-HF:\My Project\app\sr…-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang}' When i am tring to sync the build